# generating google api key in android

Tags: android

I am developing an android application which involves google map activity.I have done all the coding part.Now want to generate the google api key for my system.Can anybody help in this regard.Thanks in advance
Tushar Sahni

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know is explained in the [documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/el/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html). Copying from there:

Run this command to generate a certificate:

```
$ keytool -list -alias alias_name -keystore my-release-key.keystore
```

(Rename alias_name and my-release-key.keystore to something meaningful)

The result from the above command will be something like this:

```
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 94:1E:43:49:87:73:BB:E6:A6:88:D7:20:F1:8E:B5:98
```

Then go to [http://code.google. com/android/maps-api-signup.html](http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html) and follow the instructions to register your certificate.

Comment: I am not getting u,,,,Kgiannakakis .Can u explain in simple steps how to do in cmd....I will be greatly thankful to you....Thanks in advance Tushar

Comment: I've included a link in my answer. Have you read this document?

Comment: yeah,,,,kgiannakakis...I have done in cmd.cd.. Then what to do???Can u elaborate a bit..........Thanks in advance....Tushar

Comment: I've tried to be more specific. What exactly you don't understand?

Comment: can u send me a screenshot of how did u generated an api key in ur system,,,,I will be very thankful to you....Tushar